# Rewrite PyroCMS blog URLS?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, pyrocms

Say I have `example.com` set up with a PyroCMS installation, everything is working fine.

I've created a few posts on the blog and categorised them, so I end up with URLs like the following:

```
example.com/blog/category/foo
example.com/blog/category/bar
```

I'd like to access those categories with much shorter URLs, like the following:

```
example.com/foo
example.com/bar
```

I've tried the following (and several variations on it) in the `.htaccess` but gotten nothing but 500 errors and infinite redirects. It's the [standard file as per github](https://github.com/pyrocms/pyrocms/blob/2.3/develop/.htaccess) that I'm working with, with my additions below:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule foo /blog/category/foo [L]
</IfModule>
```

If anyone knows how to do this it would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure this is possible and preferable at the `.htaccess` level but I've settled for a PHP based approach for now. Specifically, adding some routes to the top of my `system/cms/config/routes.php`:

```
$route['(foo)'] = 'blog/category/$1';
$route['(bar)'] = 'blog/category/$1';
```

I had a follow up question of how to get this to work with `examples.com/` (i.e. the site root), this approach doesn't work for that though unfortunately.